# URL Rewriting in IIS does nothing at all

Tags: iis, iis-8

I have a website hosted on "xyz.com". In that website, for urls with "xyz.com/cnapi/...", I am redirecting the requests to "abc.com:3000/...".

To do so, I have created following rule
[image: Inbound Rule]
[image: Rule redirect]

The regex I am using is `cnapi/?(.+)$`. I tested the pattern for "xyz.com/cnapi/default.html", and it worked.

But when I enter same url (xyz.com/cnapi/default.html), it doesn't redirect. It displays default.html instead of redirecting to google.com.

P.S. My final redirect will be "http://ipaddress:3000/...". For now, I am using google.com to test the redirect.

Comment: Common mistake number 1 https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59

Comment: Umm, I am a bit confused. No. 1 issue talks about putting url into the rule. I didn't do that.

Comment: Check the condition example I wrote and see why yours is wrong.